# How to enable Mobile hotspot (from Anniversary Update) in command line

Tags: networking, windows-10, command-line, windows-10-v1607, hotspot

I want to enable [new Mobile hotspot from Aniversary Update](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/how-to-enable-and-configure-a-mobile-hotspot-in-windows-10-anniversary-update/) in command line same way as from the Window's Settings. I know that there is

```
NETSH WLAN start hostednetwork
```

but this command doesn't enable DHCP server or internet sharing. I already have a task which runs a script on network change to enable hotspot after boot. But I can only enable old "hostednetwork" from the previous Window's version and this doesn't work the same way as new "Mobile hotspot" from Aniversary Update (you have to [change your setting](http://lifehacker.com/turn-your-windows-10-computer-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot-1724762931) to "allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection").

Also if I enable "hostednetwork", I will still see that Mobile hotspot is disabled in Settings and if I started "hostednetwork" after the boot, I won't get access to the internet although everything works great through Mobile hotspot (from Settings).

Comment: hostednetwork is different from mobile hotspot as far as I know, because I can use mobile hotspot on my WiFi adapter but not hostednetwork because my WiFi adapter driver didn't support hostednetwork!